# C# Code Not Recognizing Itself?

Tags: c#, constructor, public

I'm so fed up, I don't know what's going wrong here. I've got a `DLGAnalysis` object with a constructor with one parameter, and I'm calling the constructor from a Unit Test class.

Here's the `DLGAnalysis` Object:

```
class DLGAnalysis
{
    public DLGAnalysis(string DLG)
    {
        _DLG = DLG;
        _namespaceAnalyses = new List<NamespaceAnalysis>();
    }
}
```

There's more to that class but it doesn't affect the problem. Here's the unit test segment:

```
[TestClass]
public class DLGAnalysisTests
{
    // Blue line here
    private DLGAnalysis dlgAnalysis;
    private const string TestDLGName = "TestDLGName";

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        // Error here
        dlgAnalysis = new DLGAnalysis(TestDLGName);
    }
}
```

The blue line under "DLGAnalysis" says:

```
'AnalysisXMLParser.DLGAnalysis' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

And the red line under `new DLGAnalysis(TestDLGName)` says:

```
'AnalysisXMLParser.DLGAnalysis' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

The `DLGAnalysis` object clearly has a public constructor with 1 argument. I have no idea what is going on here. What's the problem? Should I just delete the file and start over?

Comment: public class DLGAnalysis

Comment: add `public` before `class`

Comment: If you dlgAnalysis in the same executable or is it in a different DLL? Does the problem also arise if you define class DlgAnalysys public?

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to set the protection level of your class

```
 public class DLGAnalysis // <== public
 {
```

Not setting a protection level defaults that class to `internal`.

As your unit test project is probably in a different assembly, it can't access `internal` classes.

Comment: just for more clarity, not setting a protection level defaults that class to `internal`

Comment: I...wow. I feel so incompetent. I had been sitting here retyping the `public` in front of `DLGAnalysis` hoping something would kick in.

Comment: @KieranPaddock don't forget to give Accepted Answers the Green Check mark (under it's up and down arrows) when you are satisfied.